# how to format a date time variable in asp.net mvc using @HTML.DisplayNameFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, format

I have this statement in my view that as follows:

```
<th>           
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
</th>
```

all I'm trying to do is format the release date so that it will be in the format of mm/dd/yyyy. I've searched loads and haven't come across anything that is exactly what I'm looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm relatively new to coding.

Here is my Model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMovie2.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }

    public class DummyModel : Movie
    {
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie2.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>           
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Please share your model

Comment: `DisplayNameFor()` outputs the property name (or the result of any `DisplayAttribute`. Did you mean `@Html.DisplayFor()`?

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
the line above is the one where I need to format the date into MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: The model in your view is `Movie`, not `DummyModel`. You need to apply the attribute to the `ReleaseDate` property in `Movie`, not `DummyModel`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with the [DisplayFormatAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) :

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMovie2.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<MvcMovie2.Models.Movie>` therefore you cannot use the html helper like you did. Instead separate your code in partial views that are strongly type to `MvcMovie2.Modes.Movie` :

Code for the actual view :

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie2.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    @Html.Partial("Header")
    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    {
        @Html.Partial("Movie", item)
    }
</table>
```

Code for the `Header.cshtml` partial view :

```
@model MvcMovie2.Models.Movie

<tr>       
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </th>
    <th>           
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
```

Code for the `Movie.cshtml` partial view :

```
@model MvcMovie2.Models.Movie

<tr>        
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I put the class declaration in my controller but it gives me an error that I'm missing a reference on the DateFormatString. I've been searching but I can't find anything in regards to that that should be included at the top of the controller file. Suggestions?

Comment: Add a reference to the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations  assembly to your project, then add a using statement to that namespace.

Comment: I think there's something between using DisplayFor and DisplayNameFor. Using DisplayFor causes a compiler error stating that my class does not contain a definition for ReleaseDate and using DisplayNameFor lets the program work just not the way I want it to. Also, is it supposed to be DateFormatString or DataFormatString? DateFormatString doesn't compile but the other does.

Comment: Please update you question and provide the full code of your model and view.

Comment: It's DataFormatString, I misstyped it in my answer.

Comment: Please update your question with your code, it's a pain to read it.

Comment: My original question has been updated with the code. Whenever I try to run the program I get an error that says " CS1061: 'IEnumerable<Movie>' does not contain a definition for 'ReleaseDate' and no extension method 'ReleaseDate' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Movie>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" 
but you can clearly see in my Movie model that ReleaseDate is in there. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. All I had to do was put this using clause in my model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

then I put this line of code above my code that defined my Release Date:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
```

and then it worked perfectly, I didn't have to change anything in the view.